# Confirm pop up and pass php value to js with input image as submit

Tags: php, javascript

Bascially when a user hits the delete button, the script must confirm from user if he wants to delete or not.  I want to pass the id of a row.  I am using input type="image" and onclick brings up the box.  How do I pass $row_id['id] to the js script.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function show_confirm()
{
var r=confirm("Do you want to delete");
if (r==true)
  {
    window.location = "delete.php";
  //alert("You pressed OK!");
  }
else
  {

  }
}
</script>


<input type="image" src='../images/delete.jpg' width='30px' height='30px' style="position:relative; top:0px;" onclick="show_confirm()">
```

Comment: Could you post the code in your php script 'delete.php'

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
    <input type="image" src='../images/delete.jpg' 
      width='30px' height='30px' style="position:relative; top:0px;" 
      onclick="show_confirm(<?php echo $row_id["id"]; ?>)" />​
```

and get id in javascript function,

```
function show_confirm(id)
{
if (confirm("Do you want to delete image-"+id))
  {
    window.location = "delete.php";
  //alert("You pressed OK!");
  }
else
  {

  }
}
```

Comment: Is it safer to delete in the r==true or delete.php?

Comment: @Jean, it's up to you. if you want to get confirm from user to delete image, you should change delete.php,so I think this is more useful.

Answer (score 0):

Give an id to your image, e.g. `<img id="myId" src="...">` and read the particular id from javascript like this: `id = document.getElementById("myId").id;`

Answer (score 0):

Just to build on what @ocanal said, you would now have the id and you could append it to the end of the url to have your php script delete the image:

```
window.location = "delete.php?imageId=" + id;
```

This would pass the id of the image to your script to be deleted.